# How can i solver my problem with update version in angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with the update version of angular js from  1.58 to 1.82, because there is a problem with the "ui-router", this is my bower.json :

```
      "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.8.2",
    "angular-i18n": "1.7.2",
    "angular-dynamic-locale": "0.1.37",
    "angular-translate": "2.18.1",
    "angular-translate-loader-static-files": "2.18.1",
    "angular-translate-storage-local": "2.18.1",
    "angular-translate-handler-log": "2.18.1",
    "angular-animate": "1.8.2",
    "angular-bootstrap": "1.3.3",
    "angular-cookies": "1.8.2",
    "angular-ui-router": "1.0.29",
    "ng-pub-sub": "1.1.1",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.8.2",
    "ng-csv": "0.3.6"
  },

    "resolutions": {
        "angular": "1.8.2"
      }
```

And on Google Chrome I have this error :
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
And this warning :
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:9998/lib/js/angular-ui-router.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Why ?

Comment: The waning unlikely related to the problem. Usually angular gives a url to the full error after `[$injector:modulerr]`, can you post it here?

Comment: In general the `$injector:modulerr` error came from a dependency not resolved from the AngularJs Dependency Injection.